# WiFi drivers: why unique comp + router pair = 20x slower network?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, network-manager

Update 14 Oct 2014: whole post

---

**The situation (by speedtest.net):**

My notebook built-in wifi reaches internet speed max of 3.3 Mb/s for a specific router.
Other computers can get 20-40 Mb/s there.
One of them is also `Ubuntu` but different driver (`iwl3945` as I remember).

---

**Debugged as below:**

- speedtest.net result: http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/3832053617 (`nm-tool` below)
- the notebook can reach even 50 Mb/s but not with that router;
- built-in wifi `n` = 3.3 Mb/s, temporary USB adapter `g` = 15 Mb/s;
- for a riddle notebook next to the router does not speed up (that stronger (100) network at `nm-tool` is actually broadcasted by the same router but managed by ISP, login and pass required);
- changed channel from Auto 11 to 1, more stable for my notebook;
- tried 5 GHz network but that's not visible for my notebook;
- I can not disable all but `n` standard because this is a team network (should try sometime though);
- dependless on various distances from the router;

**Have not tried:**

- different driver (is there?);

**Any ideas on settings, drivers or anything actually?**

---

**lspci | grep -i "wireless"**

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

**nm-tool** - 2 meters from the router

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [Agrosh] ------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            ath9k
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        44:6D:57:7F:77:49

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           58 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    UPC Wi-Free:     Infra, 46:32:C8:34:40:69, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 100 WPA2 Enterprise
    UPC824107:       Infra, 4C:72:B9:45:3A:FF, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 52 WPA2
    UPC Wi-Free:     Infra, 4E:72:B9:45:3A:F1, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 50 WPA2 Enterprise
    DIRECT-AY-BRAVIA:Infra, 72:18:8B:D0:4B:4E, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 49 WPA2
    UPC1382728:      Infra, 8C:04:FF:F4:77:CE, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 39 WPA WPA2
    UPC Wi-Free:     Infra, FE:94:E3:11:EE:FB, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37 WPA2 Enterprise
    UPC0041263:      Infra, FC:94:E3:0B:66:B3, Freq 2442 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 32 WPA WPA2
    UPC Wi-Free:     Infra, FE:94:E3:0B:66:B5, Freq 2442 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 32 WPA2 Enterprise
    UPC198160:       Infra, 4C:72:B9:04:05:6D, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 29 WPA2
    UPC Wi-Free:     Infra, 4E:72:B9:04:05:6F, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA2 Enterprise
    UPC0041437:      Infra, FC:94:E3:11:EE:F9, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA WPA2
    UPC Wi-Free:     Infra, 8E:04:FF:F4:77:C0, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 22 WPA2 Enterprise
    UPC Wi-Free:     Infra, C6:27:95:77:D1:30, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 17 WPA2 Enterprise
    UPC0041704:      Infra, 24:EC:99:E5:B8:C8, Freq 2442 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 17 WPA WPA2
    Livebox-7149:    Infra, 68:1A:B2:58:71:49, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 15 WPA WPA2
    UPC1816193:      Infra, C4:27:95:77:D1:3E, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 12 WPA WPA2
    UPC Wi-Free:     Infra, 26:EC:99:E5:B8:CA, Freq 2442 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 12 WPA2 Enterprise
    UPC1373890:      Infra, 8C:04:FF:80:AC:57, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 9 WPA WPA2
    Orange_FunSpot:  Infra, 6E:1A:B2:58:71:49, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 15
    *Agrosh:         Infra, 44:32:C8:34:40:67, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 70 WPA WPA2
    UPC Wi-Free:     Infra, 06:7C:34:3D:CA:FB, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 20 WPA WPA2 Enterprise
    ZTE_904C:        Infra, C8:64:C7:41:90:4C, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 19 WPA
    AHPN:            Infra, F8:D1:11:93:57:0A, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 14 WPA WPA2
    Ako:             Infra, 00:24:B2:45:44:68, Freq 2432 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 12 WPA2
    ABBIURO:         Infra, D8:5D:4C:A2:87:32, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 14 WEP
    michalina:       Infra, 64:7C:34:3D:CA:FB, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 19 WPA WPA2
    DIRECT-hY-BRAVIA:Infra, 12:A0:96:D4:BA:22, Freq 2417 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.10
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             62.179.1.63
    DNS:             62.179.1.62


- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        A0:B3:CC:C8:88:24

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off
```

Comment: It's actually better to be more than 5 feet (1.5 meters) away from the router.

Comment: Normally I'm ~ 10 meters away. Anyway signal strength seems not to be an issue as gradually closer to router & higher signal did not change the speed.

Comment: My guess is that you need to get off that channel (2462) as you've got a conflicting network 10+ the strength of yours. Also, if you can't even change the channel I'd suggest some aftermarket firmware for that router if you own it.

Comment: This is why I have mentioned about 2 more comps with 40 Mb/s on same router and channel. Also no difference while closer to router. I can change the channel (tried 4 based on other networks) but this is not applied since still goes on 11 and when I restart the router with channel 4 set, I can not connect at all... Few times spent a while on resetting router back to Auto channel = 11.

Comment: Other Ubuntu comp is driven by `iwl3945` not as mine `ath9k`. And there is 13 Mb/s same network while 50 strength and I'm having 2-3 Mb/s with 83+ strength. It's rather not interference because I had same low speed while stronger & close channel networks were not broadcasting.

Comment: All your devices appear to be 80211n capable but it looks like you are using b+g mixed or auto mode. Have you tried setting your router to "wireless-n only" @ 40MHz-wide?

Comment: Updated the whole post.